# ToggleButton Error On Eclipse Android Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Whenever I drag a toggle button in Eclipse it throws this error and my graphical layout is greyed out

```
Exception raised during rendering: -1 Exception details are logged in
Window > Show View > Error LogThe graphics preview in the layout
editor may not be accurate: Different corner sizes are not supported
in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session) Path.isConvex is not
supported. (Ignore for this session)
```

Any fix for it?

I use Eclipse not Android Studio, since Android Studio hangs on my PC

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error and don't worry...if you're using eclipse make sure that your system meets the required hardware requirements for running eclipse....and also again drag and drop the Toggle Button and wait for some time(approx. 1 min) and then see if it shows your Toggle Button or not.

Comment: yes it meets all requirements and work for everything except togglebutton and i tired adding again and waiting for 1min doesnot help but when i run the app toggle is shown properly on emulator but error only in eclipse and tried restarting again eclipse still graphical layout is greyed out

Comment: then try installing a newer version of eclipse !